# Hailstone Sequence (Java)

Tags: java

So I have this problem that was assigned to me where you  have write  a program that asks for a starting integer and an ending integer and returns the length of the longest [hailstone sequence](http://plus.maths.org/content/mathematical-mysteries-hailstone-sequences), the number between the start and the end where it occurs, and the actual sequence.

I figured out most of it, but I was stuck on printing out the actual largest sequence. If anyone could please help me on this, it would really help. Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hailstone
{


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int first, last, counter = -500, highestSequence = 0, highestNumber = 0, number = 0, sequence = 0;

    System.out.println("First candidate?");
    first = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Last candidate?");
    last = scan.nextInt();

        for(int x = first; x <= last; x++)
        {
            number = x;
            counter = 1;

            while(number !=1)
            {
                if(number % 2 == 0) //even
                {
                    number = number/2;
                }
                else //odd
                {
                    number = number*3 + 1;
                }

            counter++; //counts sequence
            }
            if(counter > highestSequence)
            {
                highestSequence = counter;
                highestNumber = x;

                sequence = number; 
            }

        }
        System.out.println("longest sequence of " + highestSequence + " occurs at " + highestNumber);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply take your `highestNumber` and run the code that computes the sequence on it to print it. It will help if you extract the code to a separate method (just a sketch, verify it and modify it yourself):

```
   public int checkSequence(int x, boolean print) {
        int number = x;
        while(number !=1)
        {
            if (print) {
               System.out.print(number + " ");
            }
            if(number % 2 == 0) //even
            {
                number = number/2;
            }
            else //odd
            {
                number = number*3 + 1;
            }

        counter++; //counts sequence
        }
        return counter;
   }
```

In your program you will then call `checkSequence(x, false)` and after you're done you'll call `checkSequence(highestNumber, true)`.

Comment: Is the counter out of scope?