# How to return an ArrayList <Integer>?

Tags: java

I am working on a question from an assignment. It is called the 3n+1 problem. The task is to get an integer from user (not 1 or negative number) and based on the number input (n), if it is even - divide by 2, and if it is negative - multiple n * 3 + 1.

The method I MUST use is as follows:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getHailstoneSequence(int n) {
```

^ this part is mandatory for my assignment, so it is necessary for me to work with an ArrayList of Integers.

I am struggling to make my program work. I can't figure out if I should store the input in the main method OR in my definition class. I also am not sure how to have the loop execute for even numbers in the main method without the redundancy of already having it stated in the definition class ( where my getHailstoneSequence() method is located).

Here is the code I have: **(DEFINITION CLASS)**

```
package question7;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HailstoneSequence {

    // Method for computing the Hailstone Sequence:

    public static ArrayList<Integer> getHailstoneSequence(int n) {

        ArrayList<Integer> hailstoneSequence = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            if (n % 2 == 0) {

                n = n / 2;

                hailstoneSequence.add(n);
            }
            else {
                n = (n * 3) + 1;
                hailstoneSequence.add(n);
            }
            return hailstoneSequence;
    }
 }
```

I am unsure how to include the method I created above into the main method for printing. I want the output to look like this (example):

5 is odd, so we make 3N+1: 16
16 is even, so we take half: 8
8 is even, so we take half: 4
4 is even, so we take half: 2
2 is even, so we take half: 1

And have the program stop whe n = 1

Here is what I have in my **main method** to date:

```
package question7;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HailstoneSequenceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner hailstone = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("To begin, please enter a positive integer that is not 1:");
        int n = hailstone.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Integer> list = HailstoneSequence.getHailstoneSequence(n);

        for (int sequence : list) {
            try {
                if (n > 1) {

                    System.out.println("Great choice! Let's begin!");
                    System.out.println();
                    while (n % 2 == 0) {    
                               System.out.println(n +
                      " is even, so we take half: " +
                    HailstoneSequence.getHailstoneSequence(n));
                    list.add(n);
                        if (n == 1) break;
                        while (n % 2 != 0) {
                            System.out.println(n + 
                               " is odd, so I make 3n+1: " + 
                                 HailstoneSequence.getHailstoneSequence(n));
                            list.add(n);        
                            if (n == 1) break;
                        }

                        // while (n == 1) {
                        // System.out.println(sequence);
                        // break;
                    }

                }
            }

            catch (Exception error) {
                while (n <= 1) {

                    System.out
                            .println("You did not enter a valid positive, greater than 1 integer. Please try again: ");
                    System.out.println();

                    n = hailstone.nextInt();

                }

                // End of HailstoneSequenceTest class

                hailstone.close();

            }

        }
    }
}

// }
```

Does anyone have any idea where I am going wrong? I know my code is probably wrong if multiple ways, I am just not sure where to start.

Do I need a for loop to hold the characteristics and increment ect.. ?

When I try to do this the way I know, it says I must return a ArrayList not an Int .

Please advise.

Comment: *Please* format your code!

Comment: Re-read your assignment. I very much doubt a method named `getHailstoneSequence()`and returning a list is supposed to return a list of a single element.

Comment: it does not state that it must be a single element, it just gives me an error whenever I try and include anything other than an int, or if I try and simply print an int. It wants the arrayList and I am unsure how to use this. @JBNizet

Comment: you said negative number is not a valid input but then you said "if it is negative number multiply n*3+1"

Comment: It is a sequence: https://plus.maths.org/content/mathematical-mysteries-hailstone-sequences

You have to return *the sequence* which is more than 1 number. Use a while/for loop for that.

Comment: @ForeverStudent sorry, I meant odd.

Comment: @Idos would you mind giving me a rough example of what the while/for loop would look like ? Not looking for an answer to my problem just an example so I can work on it.

Comment: sorry to be so harsh but your code logic is downright bad. If I were to write an answer I would probably start from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your code i have modified and its working,

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getHailstoneSequence(int n) {

        ArrayList<Integer> hailstoneSequence = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            while(true)
            {
                if(n==1)break;
            if (n % 2 == 0) { //if the remainder of n/2 is 0, then the number is even
                 hailstoneSequence.add(n);
                n = n / 2;
            }

            else {
                 hailstoneSequence.add(n);
                n = (n * 3) + 1;
            }
            }
            return hailstoneSequence;


    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner hailstone = new Scanner(System.in);//ask user for initial number input
        System.out.println("To begin, please enter a positive integer that is not 1:");

        int n = hailstone.nextInt();

        ArrayList<Integer> list = AS.getHailstoneSequence(n);
        int i=0;
// loop through all the numbers
        for (int sequence : list) {
            try
            {

                    if(sequence==1)break;
                    if(sequence%2==0)
                    {
                        System.out.println(sequence + " is even, so I take half: " + (sequence/2));
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println(sequence+ " is odd, so I make 3n+1: " + ((3*sequence)+1));
                    i++;

            }


            catch (Exception error) {
                while (n <= 1) {

                    System.out
                            .println("You did not enter a valid positive, greater than 1 integer. Please try again: ");
                    System.out.println();

                    n = hailstone.nextInt();

                }
}
```

and its out put is as,

```
To begin, please enter a positive integer that is not 1:
12
12 is even, so I take half: 6
6 is even, so I take half: 3
3 is odd, so I make 3n+1: 10
10 is even, so I take half: 5
5 is odd, so I make 3n+1: 16
16 is even, so I take half: 8
8 is even, so I take half: 4
4 is even, so I take half: 2
2 is even, so I take half: 1
The process took 9 to reach 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible answer can be found here:

[Hailstone Sequence (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736087/hailstone-sequence-java)

You can simply adapt this code to work with the arraylist instead of just assigning it to the variable

So something like this:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getHailstoneSequence(int n) {
  ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  while(n !=1)
  {
    result.add(number);
    if(n % 2 == 0) //even
    {
      n = n/2;
    } 
    else //odd
    {
      n= n*3 + 1;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This method should return the whole sequence.

The sequence starts with the number entered by the user. So that should be the first element in the returned list:

```
list.add(n);
```

It ends when the number becomes 1. You should thus have a loop that ends when `n` becomes 1:

```
 while (n != 1) {
     ...
 }
```

Inner elements should be obtained by computing the next sequence value from the previous one, and adding it to the list:

```
n = computeNextSequenceValue(n);
list.add(n);
```

I let you assemble the pieces of the puzzle. This is an assignment after all.

Answer (score 1):

I had a go, here you check the preconditions of your input in the main method. Then call your rules recursively until you hit the end condition.

```
public class MakeItRain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("To begin, please enter a positive integer that is not 1:");
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = userInput.nextInt();

        if (n <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("I told you to enter a positive number! Wtf is " + n);
        }
        if (n == 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("I told you to not enter 1! Come on man!");
        }

        List<Integer> hailstones = HailstoneSequence.getHailstoneSequence(n);
        System.out.println(hailstones);
    }

    private static class HailstoneSequence {

        public static List<Integer> getHailstoneSequence(int n) {
            List<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<>();
            if (recurse(sequence, n)) {
                return sequence;
            }
            return sequence;
        }

        private static boolean recurse(List<Integer> sequence, int input) {
            int currentHailstone = getNewHailstone(input);
            sequence.add(currentHailstone);

            if (sequenceComplete(currentHailstone)) {
                return true;
            }
            return recurse(sequence, currentHailstone);
        }

        private static int getNewHailstone(int hailstone) {
            if (isEven(hailstone)) {
                hailstone /= 2;
            } else {
                hailstone = (hailstone * 3) + 1;
            }
            return hailstone;
        }

        private static boolean isEven(int n) {
            return n % 2 == 0;
        }

        private static boolean sequenceComplete(int rollingResult) {
            return rollingResult == 1;
        }
    }
}
```

66 Result:

[image: 66 Result]

Error Result:

[image: -5 result]

Comment: The printed result is wrong. How can you go from 76 to 19 by dividing by 2? An iterative solution is much simpler (and efficient, and scalable).

Comment: shame :-) was more showing him how to split the main class and preconditions from his work. (*fixed - it was missing adding it to the list when 1st recursed*)

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want.....

```
import java.util.ArrayList;       
import java.util.List;    

public class HailstoneSequence    
{     
     public static ArrayList<Integer> getHailstoneSequence( ArrayList<Integer> hailstoneSequence,int n)    
     {   
          if(n==1)   
               return hailstoneSequence;   
          if (n % 2 == 0)      
          {   
               n = n / 2;    
               hailstoneSequence.add(n);   
               getHailstoneSequence(hailstoneSequence,n);    
          }   
          else    
          {   
               n = (n * 3) + 1;   
               hailstoneSequence.add(n);            
               getHailstoneSequence(hailstoneSequence, n);        
          }        
          return hailstoneSequence;       
     }     

     public static void main(String ar[])         
     {         
         ArrayList<Integer> hailstoneSequence = new ArrayList<Integer>();     
         int n=5;     
         List<Integer> list=getHailstoneSequence(hailstoneSequence,n);    
         for(Integer i:list)    
         {    
               System.out.println(i);    
         }    

     }    
}
```

Comment: Don't solve the assignment. If you do it, at least explain your solution, and format it correctly.

Comment: I thought it is not difficult at all to understand, still i explain it, i had just uses the recursion to solve the problem..

Comment: in my solution  if n==1 the function return the list otherwise it call recursively itself based on value of n i had passed the arraylist as parameter so each time on function call it prevent creation of new arraylist object..